# Hibernate Spatial MappingException for Geometry Column

Tags: hibernate-spatial

I'm using Hibernate Spatial in a GIS application. I have an entity class, in which one of the columns is a geometry column, as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class Admin implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "gid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "adm1_name")
    private String adminName;

    @Column(name = "adm1_code")
    private String adminCode;


    /*private Integer adminLevel;*/
    @Column(name = "the_geom")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
    private Geometry geom;

    @Column(name = "pmal")
    private String pMale;

    @Column(name = "pfem")
    private String pFemale;

    public Admin() {}

    /* Getters and Setter here*/
}
```

I've done a lot of experiments, and I've eliminated hibernate configuration as the cause. I've also eliminated Spring configuration as the cause.

I think my problem may be something to do with the version of hibernate spatial I'm using; I'm using version 4.0-M1. In my earlier experiments, I realized there are some package name changes from versionn 1.x. Other details are as follows:
PostGIS JDBC: version 1.3.3,
Hibernate Core: version 3.6.10 FINAL,
Hibernate Entity Manager: version 3.6.10 FINAL, and
PostgreSQL JDBC: version 8.4-702.jdbc3

Whenever I start my server, application deployment fails with the following error:

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType, at table: #table_name# for columns: #geometry_column_name#`

Any idea on how I can solve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the renaming of the package containing GeometryUserType class in Hibernate Spatial 4.x from

`org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType` in 1.x to
`org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType` in 4.x. I also changed the PostGIS JDBC driver from 1.3.3 to 1.5.2.

So, the geometry property should be defined and mapped thus:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "the_geom", nullable = true)
private Geometry geom;
```

This sorts it out for me.

Comment: What of you want to use Point (or LineString) instead of Geometry class?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the data was being stored as expected in PostgreSQL, but retrieving it using a REST API was failing with Deserialization error.
This is what worked for me with PostgreSQL 12 & Spring Boot.

Included this in the application.properties file

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect`

pom.xml changes

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.n52.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Create the below Bean with @Configuration annnotation

```
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.JtsModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public JtsModule jtsModule() {
        return new JtsModule();
    }

}
```

And in your @Entity class, make sure

```
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.GeometryDeserializer;
import org.n52.jackson.datatype.jts.GeometrySerializer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
    
@Column(name="the_geom", columnDefinition = "POINT")
@JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = GeometryDeserializer.class)
private Point point;
```

After these changes, my Rest API returns data in the expected format

```
"point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                53.85151,
                -1.55973
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is all but for anyone who faces the same issue as me, this is my answer.

In my case, I want to insert into Mysql8 Database data in 'Geometry' mysql datatype and it works with the following configuration.

**Object**

```
......
    @Column(columnDefinition="BINARY(2048)",name = "gdata")
    private Geometry gdata; 
.....
```

**persistance.xml**

```
.......
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect"/>
......
```